# I'm following an Android tutorial to make camera app in Android Studio when I type data.getExtras() its giving an error, what should I do?

Tags: android

I'm following a video tutorial on youtube to make camera application

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH9CPeurBco

at `6:42` he wrote `data.getExtras();`. When I try to type I'am getting error on `.getExtras();` that can't resolve `method' getExtra()'`". I typed exactly as he did. What should I do now ?

**here is the code:**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, int data) {
    if (requestcode == Activity_Start_Camera_App && requestcode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "picture taken successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photoCapturedBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mPhotoCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(photoCapturedBitmap);
    }
```

Comment: `int` doesn't have a method `getExtras`. You must have copied something wrong.

Comment: ok i find the problem: its Intent data in the parameter whereas i wrote int data :( thank its solved

Comment: Np. When you get errors like this, trace the data. The first thing you should have checked was the type of the object it was giving you an error on. You would have seen that it was in fact a primitive, not an object, which explains the error.

Comment: its Intent data not int data @AliyaMalik

Comment: If you need any help then join this room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131408/android-helpers @AliyaMalik

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden a wrong method. The third parameter is `Intent` not `int`

The actual method is:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    if (requestcode == Activity_Start_Camera_App && requestcode == RESULT_OK) {

    //Toast.makeText(this, "picture taken successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap photoCapturedBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mPhotoCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(photoCapturedBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden wrong method.

It should be:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    if (requestcode == Activity_Start_Camera_App && requestcode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "picture taken successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photoCapturedBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mPhotoCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(photoCapturedBitmap);
    }
```